# MFMailComposer - Attachment size

Tags: objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposer

In my iphone application, in MFMailComposer, I m adding an attachment. When I click send it is asking to select the size -  Small, Medium, Large. I dont want that. I always want to set the attachment size to Medium. Can I control that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what to do..

Previously what i did is

```
UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1];
```

I changed this into

```
UIImage* image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5];
```

This change is the compression quality of the image attached when it is "1" it is the maximum size and the it the default functionality of MFMailComposer to ask the user for changing the size for pretty large sized images. If you change this into "0.5" the image is compressed and the size will be automatically less and it will not ask the user to change the size.